# Reordering of column data in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table like so:

```
categoryID      categoryName
----------------------------
     1            A
     2            B
     3            C
```

Now I want the user to be able to order this data according to his will. I want to remember his preferred order for future. So I thought I'd add a column `order` to the table above and make it of type `INT` and `AUTO_INCREMENT`. So now I get a table like this:

```
categoryID      categoryName    order
-------------------------------------
     1            A               1
     2            B               2
     3            C               3
     4            D               4
```

My problem is - the user now decides, to bring `categoryName` with order 4 (D in example above) up to 2 (above B in example above) such that the table would now look like:

```
categoryID      categoryName    order
-------------------------------------
     1            A               1
     2            B               3
     3            C               4
     4            D               2
```

My question is - How should I go about assigning new values to the `order` column when a reordering happens. Is there a way to do this without updating all rows in the table?

One approach that comes to mind is to make the column a `FLOAT` and give it an order of 1.5 if I want to bring it between columns with order 1,2. In this case I keep loosing precision as I reorder items.

EDIT: 
Another is to update all rows between (m, n) where m, n are the source and destination orders respectively. But this would mean running (m-n) separate queries wouldn't it?

Edit 2:
Assuming I take the `FLOAT` approach, I came up with this sql to compute the order value for an item that needs to be inserted after item with id = 2 (for example).

```
select ((
    select `order` as nextHighestOrder
    from `categories`
    where `order` > (
        select `order` as targetOrder 
        from `categories` 
        where `categoryID`=2) 
        limit 1) + (
            select `order` as targetOrder 
            from `categories` 
            where `categoryID`=2)) / 2;
```

This gives me `3.5` which is what I wanted to achieve.

Is there a better way to write this? Notice that `select order as targetOrder from categories where categoryID=9` is executed twice.

Comment: Do you actually duplicate all category names and IDs for all users?

Comment: What's the size of the data set? Renumbering all would be an option if there was only 20-30 items, but if we're in the thousands it's a different story. Actually - are they dragging this item, because that limits the number an item can jump, and only those between the source and destination need renumbering. Also are multiple users manipulating the same list?

Comment: @fge `categoryName` and `userID` (not shown in the table above) form my composite PK. `categoryID` in an `AUTO_INCREMENT` `INT`. I came to this because I don't want to allow the same user to create two categories with name 'A' but two different users' can create two categories with name 'A'.

Comment: @weston. You're right, they are dragging this item in order to reorder  them. I don't expect, in an average use case, for a user to have more than say 20 categories. Multiple users will have their categories stored in the same table, but they're not be manipulating each others categories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the number of changes is rather small you can generate a clumsy but rather efficient UPDATE statement if the you know the ids of the involved items:

```
UPDATE categories
JOIN (
    SELECT 2 as categoryID, 3 as new_order
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 as categoryID, 4 as new_order
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 as categoryID, 2 as new_order) orders
USING (categoryId)
SET `order` = new_order;
```

or (which I like less):

```
UPDATE categories
SET `order` = ELT (FIND_IN_SET (categoryID, '2,3,4'),
                   3, 4, 2)
WHERE categoryID in (2,3,4);
```

**UPD**:

Assuming that you know the current id of the category (or its name), its old position, and its new position you can use the following query for moving a category down the list (for moving up you will have to change the `between` condition and `new_rank` computation to `rank+1`):

```
SET @id:=2, @cur_rank:=2, @new_rank:=4;

UPDATE t1
JOIN (
  SELECT categoryID, (rank - 1) as new_rank
  FROM t1
  WHERE rank between @cur_rank + 1 AND @new_rank
  UNION ALL
  SELECT @id as categoryID, @new_rank as new_rank
) as r
USING (categoryID)
SET rank = new_rank;
```

Comment: Not sure if I can do this because finding out all id's between the source and target will take another query. But I love the answer for it's novelty.

Comment: I've spent a good part of the last two hours just reading up on sql and the constructs you're using. Not sure I understand completely, but I am trying. I love all the queries especially the third. Works like a charm.

Comment: @manish-gupta, I can explain =): 1) `UNION ALL` unions two queries with the same columns without applying `DISTINCT` (opposed to `UNION`); 2) `UPDATE ... JOIN` is a MySQL-specific extention to `UPDATE` 3) `USING (categoryID)` in `JOIN` is equivalent to `ON t1.categoryID = r.categoryID`

Answer (score 0):

The idea with Float sounds reasanoble, just don't show these numbers to a user -)

Whenever user moves an entry up or down, you can figure out entries above and below. Just take their Order number and find mean value - that is a new order for the entry that has been moved.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep order as integer and renumber all the items between a drag's source index and destination index because they can't drag that far, especially as only 20 odd categories. Mulit-item drags make this more complicated however.

Float is easier, but each time they move you find the middle you could very quickly run out of precission, I would write a test for this to check it doesn't finally give up working if you keep moving the 3rd item to the 2nd pos over and over.

Example:

```
1,2,3
Move 3rd to 2nd
1,1.5,2
Move 3rd to 2nd
1,1.25,1.5
Move 3rd to 2nd
1,1.125,1.25
```

Do that in an excel spread sheet and you'll find the number becomes too small for floats to deal with in about 30 iterations.

Comment: Yes. You've identified the drawback of the `float` approach. In the worst case scenario, it will break. Thanks for the tip about multi-item drags, I hadn't thought about that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's the same that @newtover suggests, but these 2 simple queries can be much easier understood by any other developer, even unexperienced.

Let's say we have a table t1:

```
id      name    position
-------------------------------------
 1      A       1
 2      B       2
 3      C       3
 4      D       4
 5     -E-      5
 6      F       6
```

Let's move item 'E' with id=5 to 2nd position:

1) Increase positions for all items between the old position of item 'E' and the desired position of 'E' (positions 2, 3, 4)

```
UPDATE t1 SET position=position+1 WHERE position BETWEEN 2 AND 4
```

2) Now there is no item at position 2, so 'E' can take it's place

```
UPDATE t1 SET position=2 WHERE id=5
```

Results, ordered by 'position'

```
id      name    position
-------------------------------------
 1      A       1
 5     -E-      2
 2      B       3
 3      C       4
 4      D       5
 6      F       6
```

Just 2 simple queries, no subqueries.

Restriction: column 'position' cannot be UNIQUE. But perhaps with some modifications it should work as well.

Haven't tested this on large datasets.