# mysql list order update(move up, move down) in one query

Tags: mysql

is there any way to move up/down list item in one query if i know only one id

something like this

```
update tbl 
   SET list_order = 
    CASE 
     WHEN id = 10  
        THEN (SELECT list_order FROM tbl 
               WHERE list_order > (SELECT list_order FROM tbl WHERE id = 10)
               ORDER BY list_order ASC LIMIT 1)
     WHEN id = (SELECT id FROM tbl 
                 WHERE list_order > (SELECT list_order FROM tbl WHERE id = 10) 
                 ORDER BY list_order ASC LIMIT 1)
        THEN (SELECT list_order FROM tbl WHERE id = 10) 
     ELSE list_order
    END
```

tbl

```
id  |  list_order
-----------------
 10 |   1    
 22 |   2
 33 |   3
```

to >

```
id  |  list_order
-----------------
 22 |   1    
 10 |   2
 33 |   3
```

my answer for this question (example MOVE UP in list row with ID 10)

```
    UPDATE tbl e
     JOIN (SELECT id, list_order FROM tbl 
          WHERE list_order < (SELECT list_order FROM tbl WHERE id = 10)
                 ORDER BY list_order DESC LIMIT 1) t1
     JOIN (SELECT list_order FROM tbl WHERE id = 10) t2
     SET e.list_order = CASE 
      WHEN e.id = 10  
        THEN t1.list_order 
      WHEN e.id = t1.id
        THEN t2.list_order 
      ELSE e.list_order
     END
```

Comment: not clear. what exactly you want to do, Please give an example

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reordering of column data in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532144/reordering-of-column-data-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

If moving id 22 up one -

```
UPDATE tbl t1
INNER JOIN tbl t2
    ON t1.list_order - 1 = t2.listorder
SET
    t1.list_order = t1.list_order - 1,
    t2.list_order = t2.list_order + 1
WHERE t1.id = 22;
```

Comment: no .. this works only when you have right list_order(1,2,3). if u delete row with list_order (2) this not work anymore

Comment: That was my intention. If this is the only code being used to modify list_order then it does not matter. What other code modifies the list_order? Why does the list end up with holes? When deleting item in position two you should subtract 1 from all entries with position > 2. Similarly, if inserting at position 3 you should add 1 to all entries with position >= 3.

Comment: Fair enough. I was giving the simplest query based on maintaining a contiguous set for the list order. I like to keep these things contiguous but it is unnecessary, just something I like to do.