# Best strategy to update mysql rows with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Say I've 5 rows with `id`, `catname` and `order` fields:

```
+----+----------+-----+  
| id | catname  |order|
+----+----------+-----+  
|  1 | cat1     |   2 |
|  2 | cat2     |   1 |
|  3 | cat3     |   3 | 
|  4 | cat4     |   5 |
|  5 | cat5     |   4 |
+----+----------+-----+
```

and I want to update the order of these 5 categories from an array, e.g.:

```
array(1 => 3, 2 => 4, 3 => 5, 4 => 1, 5 => 2)
```

What is the best practice? To select each row and update order fields with its corresponding order in array? Or to create a new table containing order array of all these categories and use it for ordering and linking the two tables with a join statement using for example userid?

Comment: See if this thread of mine helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532144/reordering-of-column-data-in-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it in one query, you can generate your SQL query as follows (assuming the keys are the existing `order` values):

```
$orders = array(
    1 => 3,
    2 => 4,
    3 => 5,
    4 => 1,
    5 => 2,
);

$sql = 'UPDATE category SET order = CASE order ';

foreach ($orders as $old => $new) {
    $sql .= "WHEN $old THEN $new ";
}

$sql .= 'END';
```

If the keys are the `id` entries, use `CASE id` instead of `CASE order`.

Comment: thanks , but please note that my array means: key-> id   value->order not key->old   value->new

Comment: OK, then in that case, just change to `CASE id` instead of `CASE order`.

Comment: If that's the case, may I humbly direct you towards [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

You may could assign them negative values with the new order and then multiply the negative values with -1.

```
array(1->-3,2->-4,3->-3,4->-1,5->-2)
```

But you will have to update the rows each themselves by looping through your array:

```
update yourTable set order=-3 where order=1;
```

And later use

```
update yourTable set order=-1*order where order < 0;
```

Comment: In order to avoid to update a value twice, e.g. first you update 2->4 and then 4->1 which would mean that 2->1 too. Putting negative values can avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the order data in the rows you're going to be selecting/fetching anyway is going to be faster than a join with a different table for sure. In terms of updating, it doesn't really matter - provided you have good indexes in place. So, I would go with the one table approach.