# Change multiple values in single column MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
+-------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| ID    | name       | dept_name | salary    |
+-------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| 10101 | Srinivasan |         0 |  71500.00 |
| 12121 | Wu         |         0 |  90000.00 |
| 15151 | Mozart     |         0 |  40000.00 |
| 22222 | Einstein   |         0 |  95000.00 |
| 32343 | El Said    |         0 |  60000.00 |
| 33456 | Gold       |         0 |  87000.00 |
| 45565 | Katz       |         0 |  82500.00 |
| 58583 | Califieri  |         0 |  62000.00 |
| 76543 | Singh      |         0 |  80000.00 |
| 76766 | Crick      |         0 |  72000.00 |
| 83821 | Brandt     |         0 | 101200.00 |
| 98345 | Kim        |         0 |  80000.00 |
+-------+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

I want to change the values in the dept_name column to values (all different) without saving and recreating the table. Is there a way to do this?

Desired output:

```
+-------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| ID    | name       | dept_name | salary    |
+-------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| 10101 | Srinivasan |         1 |  71500.00 |
| 12121 | Wu         |         2 |  90000.00 |
| 15151 | Mozart     |         3 |  40000.00 |
| 22222 | Einstein   |         2 |  95000.00 |
| 32343 | El Said    |         2 |  60000.00 |
| 33456 | Gold       |         3 |  87000.00 |
| 45565 | Katz       |         1 |  82500.00 |
| 58583 | Califieri  |         3 |  62000.00 |
| 76543 | Singh      |         1 |  80000.00 |
| 76766 | Crick      |         1 |  72000.00 |
| 83821 | Brandt     |         2 | 101200.00 |
| 98345 | Kim        |         2 |  80000.00 |
+-------+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: m not getting your question..!!

Comment: No if you want set same value for all then you can use update query but you said you want all different. so i think its not possible.

Comment: instead post the output you want..

Comment: how did you gt the value of the dept name?

Comment: The new value or the old value?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend joining on a subquery with UNIONs. Look at my answer here for an example: [Reordering of column data in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532144/reordering-of-column-data-in-mysql/8534628#8534628)

Comment: I do not know what the ID's will be or am to assume the table is very large (50,000 tuples).

Comment: You don't know what the IDs will be? What are you actually trying to do then? Are you trying to do this: http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/update-multiple-rows-with-different-values-and-a-single-sql-query/ ?

Comment: I do not know PHP so that is difficult for me to understand. I am doing this in java, I just want to take the old table and make it look like the new table. I realize I could store all this in a ResultSet and then change it and put it back into the table, I was wondering if there is a different way to do so. And with the assumption that there are 50,000 rows so I cannot go through for each ID and change the dept_name manually. I have a string in order with the values I want, just need to insert them into the dept_name column.